# How to modify the location of .condarc file?

Tags: conda, miniconda

I have recently installed Miniconda3 on windows. Conda expects the .condarc file to be located in the windows "home directory" C:\Users\user.name\.condarc.

How can I tell conda to look for a .condarc file in a different location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: You can set `CONDARC=/path/to/.condarc` or put the file in one of the paths below.

See the [condarc documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#searching-for-condarc) for a list of paths where conda searches for the `.condarc` file. You can place your `.condarc` any of these paths (the paths that apply to your operating system).

I have included the relevant information below.

```py
if on_win:
 SEARCH_PATH = (
     'C:/ProgramData/conda/.condarc',
     'C:/ProgramData/conda/condarc',
     'C:/ProgramData/conda/condarc.d',
 )
else:
 SEARCH_PATH = (
     '/etc/conda/.condarc',
     '/etc/conda/condarc',
     '/etc/conda/condarc.d/',
     '/var/lib/conda/.condarc',
     '/var/lib/conda/condarc',
     '/var/lib/conda/condarc.d/',
  )

 SEARCH_PATH += (
     '$CONDA_ROOT/.condarc',
     '$CONDA_ROOT/condarc',
     '$CONDA_ROOT/condarc.d/',
     '~/.conda/.condarc',
     '~/.conda/condarc',
     '~/.conda/condarc.d/',
     '~/.condarc',
     '$CONDA_PREFIX/.condarc',
     '$CONDA_PREFIX/condarc',
     '$CONDA_PREFIX/condarc.d/',
     '$CONDARC',
 )
```

> `CONDA_ROOT` is the path for your base conda install. `CONDA_PREFIX` is the path to the current active environment.

If one has multiple `.condarc` files, conda will merge the information [using the following strategies](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#conflict-merging-strategy):

> - Lists - merge
> - Dictionaries - merge
> - Primitive - clobber [i.e., overwrite]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 
I want to locate my .bashrc in my home directory, i.e. ~\.condarc. For that, I have created a HOME environment variable. This was working on my previous windows environment, but it is not working anymore!

Comment: By setting the CONDARC variable, I see with the `conda info` command that I have now two config files that are used by conda: user config file, and populated config file. It seems that conda picks some parameters from both of those files, but I cannot understand based on what rules.

Comment: @BayesianMonk - please see my updated answer. i include information on how multiple condarc files are merged

Comment: Thanks @jakub for the detailed answer. The problem I am facing is that it is ignoring the `envs_dirs` variable is ignored, and it continues to select the one in the windows user home directory.

Comment: `CONDARC` seems not work on on conda 4.13.0. Is there any other why to change the location? I am running conda in docker environment and I am not able to write default config file without root previlledge.

Comment: @link89 - can you open a new question and put a link here? I’m happy to take a look. Please include the dockerfile in your question if you do choose to open one.

Comment: @jkr I guess I have figured it out. `CONDARC` decides which configuration file to read when running the `conda` command, but it doesn't decide where to write new items. To write config to the file you want you have to specific it in the command line, for example `conda config -f $CONDARC --add channels conda-forge`